# How to make a scatterplot in R with category-specific colored text labels?

Tags: r, colors, plot, scatter-plot

I am still pretty new to R and plotting. I have several 2D matrices that are variations of

```
matrix <- matrix(c(0,1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1,0), 5, 2)
```

They are all associated with a single data frame of two columns with category labels, which is stored elsewhere in

```
df <- data.frame(c("Class1","Class2","Class3","Class4","Class5"), c("A","B","C","B","A"))
```

What I want to do is make a scatterplot of `matrix` with points labels from the first column of `df`, and color-coded to category labels in the second column. E.g., I need to specify `A=red`, `B=blue`, and then the scatterplot should display points associated with `Class1` and `Class5` in red, `Class2` and `Class4` in blue, and so on. I can plot `matrix` using text labels associated with the Class column just fine, but can't figure out the color manipulation. Thanks in advance if you can help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A="red"; B="blue"
text( x= matrix[,1], y= matrix[,2], labels=df[,1], 
         col=c(A, B, "black")[ as.numeric(df[,2]) ])
```

Basic practice is to build a color vector and then run a selection vector through "[".

Comment: I like the ggplot method more for a few reasons, but mostly that it adds a legend automatically.

Comment: ? ... even though it didn't do what was requested?

Comment: @DWin: I'm sorry- how didn't it do what was requested?

Comment: Didn't set the colors as requested.

Comment: Given the OP's comment on my answer, it seems that wasn't something he was asking for as much as something he assumed he had to do (choose colors as opposed to having them selected)

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done using [ggplot2](http://ggplot2.org/) (which you'll first have to install). First put them all into one big data frame, also giving them some useful names:

```
colnames(matrix) = c("x", "y")
colnames(df) = c("Class", "Category")
d = cbind(matrix, df)
```

Then use `ggplot`, providing the columns of the new data frame you are interested in in the `x`, `y`, `col` (for color), and `label` places, along with `geom_text()` to indicate you want to make a plot with text:

```
library(ggplot2)
g = ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, col=Category, label=Class)) + geom_text()
print(g)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is tremendously helpful and works flawlessly!